# Using webpacker with asset images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, asset-pipeline

I am trying to use webpacker gem with Rails. The purpose is that I want to reduce compiling scss duration. Therefore, I only move scss via this https://medium.com/@coorasse/goodbye-sprockets-welcome-webpacker-3-0-ff877fb8fa79 and this is working.

The problem is that I would like to use **both Rails asset pipeline for images and webpacker.**

I tried adding resolved_paths in webpacker.yml as follows

```
 default: &default
 source_path: app/webpacker
 source_entry_path: packs
 public_output_path: packs
 cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker

 # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
 # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
 resolved_paths: ['app/assets']
```

How do I **load images in scss without moving to webpacker and still using Rails asset pipeline.**

Thanks.